# Quick Java Question: Instantiating a given class only from another?

Tags: java, class, instantiation

My problem is thus: I need a way to ensure only one given class can instantiate another.  I don't want to have to make the other a nested inner class or something dumb like that.  How do I do this?  I forget offhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the constructor private.  Create a static factory method that takes an instance of the class that is allowed access.  Have the factory method create a suitable object and use a settor on the object that is allowed access to the created object to give that class the created copy.

```
public class AllowedAccess
{
    private SecureClass secure;
    public setSecureClass( SecureClass secure )
    {
        this.secure = secure;
    }

    ...
}

public class SecureClass
{
     private SecureClass() {}

     public static void Create( AllowedAccess allowed )
     {
          allowed.setSecureClass( new SecureClass() );
     }

     ...
}
```

BTW, I'm suspicious of this design.  Seems too highly coupled to me.

Comment: It's either that or end up with a God class.

Comment: *shudder*. This is creative but insane!

Comment: I agree, but it's not my requirement.  :-)

Comment: Yeah it's a mess.  I'm still trying to wrap my brain around good practices, but my priority is still to get something out the door first and foremost.

Answer (score 8):

A private static inner class is exactly what you want. Nothing dumb about it.

```
public class Creator {
  private static class Created {
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can only protect instantiation on the package level.

```
public class Created {
  Created() {
  }
}
```

Which gives only classes from the same package access to the constructor.

Comment: Java sure doesn't want me doing this. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could make the class that is to be protected from instantiation package private.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with tvanfosson's answer and also with his comment about too high coupling. Why don't you retain more control of you class creation process by adopting an [Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) framework like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)?

IMHO creating classes with the "new" statement is to be considered a bit... obsolete, factories are to be preferred and IoC frameworks even more.

Regards

Comment: I think that's a rather narrow if not naive view. Creational patterns have their place and factories are often good. IoC may have its place but it will never replace new.

*Nothing* will ever be as clear or simple as A a = new A(); so it's preposterous to call it obsolete.